# how do i convert 12 vdc to 100 vdc to use in central phone?

Tags: dc, telephone

I need a small circuit that convert 12 vdc to 100 vdc to use in central phone that can ring the phone.the current is maximum 150 ma.how can i do it?
thanks

Comment: perhaps by googling 12V to 100V converter

Answer (score 3):

Typically you require something like 25Hz AC at high voltage (around 100VAC RMS).

You can use a ring generator chip such as the Microchip (formerly Supertex) part [shown here](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/HV461%20C071913.pdf):

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot.I think i'd better to buy a hv450 ic .It's very good that it doesn't need any big transformer.
I have another problem.I need an Internal communication between 8 phone how can I do it.Can i connect two phone directly to each other and parallel a 8 vdc with them.Is it work?
thank you very much.

Comment: Not sure what you mean here, sounds like it might be another question. The loading capability of ring generators is typically stated in RENs (ringer equivalence number). The HV450 is indicated as obsolete.